# PHP Date and JavaScript Datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

In my application, I want to use same date format using my settings.

In jQuery Datepicker, it is showing like `dd/mm/yy` for `04/09/2017`, and it is storing it in the database in the same format.

Mainly this `dd/mm/yy` is from settings, which I declared globally.

I should be able to change the format when I'm retrieving it like this.

**Date.php:**

```
<?php  
$dateformat=dd/mm/yy (from database);
$date=$showproject->start_date; 
echo date($dateformat->date_formats,strtotime($date)); 
?>
```

It is echoing like `0404/0909/1717`.

How can I get it like `04/07/2017` in PHP.

It needs to be like `d/m/Y`, but in JavaScript it needs to be like `dd/mm/yy`.

How can I solve this? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Your format needs to be `d/m/Y`. See the [documentation](http://php.net/date).

Comment: i want to convert format like d-m-Y from dd-mm-yy, after getting d-m-Y i'm changing date to this date formats

Comment: The two format strings will produce the same output, it's just the operating environments (PHP and your datepicker) which use different formatting strings to mean the same thing. So simply use the PHP d/m/Y format to echo the date, but in the JS config use dd-mm-yy if that's what's required. There's no reason you have to make them identical. Although it's not clear from your code sample how you're actually setting this up - the sample you've given isn't even valid code anyway.